# Looping multiple files into a single csv file in python

Tags: python, list, file

I am trying to process several files into a single, merged csv file using python. So far, I have

```
files = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"]

def doSomething(oldfile):
    content = []
    with open oldfile as file:
        content = file.read().splitlines()
    file.close()
    return content.reverse()

with open("newfile.txt", "w") as file:
    w = csv.writer(file, dialect = "excel-tab")
    for i in range(0, len(files)):
        w. writerows(doSomething(files[i])
file.close()
```

The new file is being created, but there is nothing in it. I am curious about what is going on.

Thanks!

Comment: `with open oldfile as file:` If this line is copied verbatim I'm surprised it runs at all.  Also, as a matter of being pythonic, replace the for loop with `for file in files: w.writerows(doSomething(file))`.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `list.reverse()` reverses the list in place and doesn't return anything so you're essentially returning `None` from your `doSomething()` function. You'll actually want to split that into two lines:

```
content.reverse()
return content
```

If you want to streamline your code, here's a suggestion:

```
def doSomething(oldfile):
    with open(oldfile, "r") as f:
        return reversed(f.read().splitlines())

files = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"]

with open("newfile.txt", "wb") as file:
    w = csv.writer(file, dialect = "excel-tab")
    for current_file in files:
        w.writerows(doSomething(current_file))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your program crashes for several reasons:

1. **`open(..)` is a function**, so you cannot write:

   ```
   with open oldfile as file:
   ```
2. a **`with`** statement for files is used to **enforce closing** of a file, so `file.close()` is actually not necessary.
3. `.reverse()` works **inplace**: it returns `None`, you can use `reversed(..)` for that.

You can fix it with:

```
files = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"]

def doSomething(oldfile):
    content = []
    with open(oldfile,'r') as file:
        return list(reversed(file))

with open("newfile.txt", "w") as file:
    w = csv.writer(file, dialect = "excel-tab")
    for oldfile in files:
        w.writerows(doSomething(oldfile))
```

I also used a `for` loop over the list, instead of the indices, since that is more "*pythonic*". Furthermore a `file` is iterable over its rows. So one can use `reversed(file)` to obtain the lines of the file in reverse.